# Using currentTarget for an 'mouseenter' event for multiples divs

Tags: jquery, html

First of all I would like to tell that I started to learn web programming a month ago and I think that the problem I am facing have an easy solution, but I could found it here. I dont know if its because its really simple that everybody knows or because I didnt found the right keywords to found it.

OK, here is my question:

I want to create few divs that will slidedown once the event mouseenter is trigger and slideup once mouseleave.

I managed to do so for one div doing:

```
$('.title').on('mouseenter', () => {
        $('.info').slideDown();
});

$('.box').on('mouseleave', () => {
    $('.info').slideUp();
});
```

But if I have more than one div with the same classes it triggers everyone.

I had also tried with 'currentTarget' doing:

```
$('.box').on('mouseenter', event => {
        $(event.currentTarget).slideDown();
});
```

But it even doesnt trigger the slideDown.... even I had done a test doing:

```
$('.box').on('mouseenter', () => {
        $('.box').slideDown();
});
```

But it doesnt works.

The HTML structure is:

```
<div class="box">
 <p class='title'>*****TITLE*****</p>
         <div class="info">
         <span>*****SUMMARY*****</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had finally found a solution:

```
$('.title').on('mouseenter', event => {
    $(event.currentTarget).siblings().slideDown();
});
$('.box').on('mouseleave', event => {
    $(event.currentTarget).children('.info').slideUp();
});
```

Doing so it behaves as I wanted triggering only '.box' children.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this easily using this keyword

```
$('.title').on('mouseenter', () => { $(this).siblings('.info').slideDown(); });
```

`$('.box').on('mouseleave', () => { $(this).find('.info').slideUp(); });`

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer but it doesnt resolve my issue, maybe the problem is in HTML or CSS, (I am really new and I may had a basic mistake) let me post further info about this: